# How to delete spam users in Joomla/mysql

Tags: mysql, joomla, phpmyadmin

In one old website I have a lot of spam registrations. What is the best way to filter and delete ONLY spam users as there are also users there that are not spam bots.

I looked in Joomla but there is no good solution for this, is there one for phpmyadmin perhaps?

Comment: Most of the time I find that spam users have not activated the accounts so you can either write a query that deletes users who have not activated from bot the #__users table and the #__user_usergroup_map table or write a quick joomla script that uses the api to do it.

Answer (score 0):

To delete the same you need to check the String pattern to create Regex or there must be 'Params' columns will blank always.

Most of the user account having 'usertype' = Registered you can delete all that users. (BE SURE IF YOU HAVE YOUR OWN REGISTERED USERS)

> delete from jos_users where usertype = 'Registered';

You have to block "New User Registration" from your Joomla site administration pane. few spam-bot using your "/index.php?option=com_users"  link to check the email address for other users.

In joomla 1.5 that is the very common issue. you need to disable the new user registration from "Global Configuration-> System tab " to stop further spam user creation.

Answer (score -1):

```
DELETE FROM jos_users WHERE 
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, " ", 1)=SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, " ", -1)
```

Comment: How do I filter spambots here first? How to know who is good and who isn't?

Comment: Check this : http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-security/spam-protection/14027

Comment: If you only delete from the user table and  not from #__user_usergroup_map plus any profile data you are going to have a mess.

Rocco can you say what you mean by "a lot" and also whethere they have anything in common? For example are none of them activated?